# Unable to access data inside alert section of elastalert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastalert

I have been trying to set up `elastalert` monitoring on my ELK stack. For the beginning I want to set up a simple rule which will generate a notification if any disk on the file system has reached 80% usage. The rule seems to be working correctly but in the `alert` section I am not able to pass the data to python script. The uncommented command in the `alert` section gives following error

`ERROR:root:Error while running alert command: Error formatting command: 'system.filesystem.mount_point'` error.

Here is my rule file. Please excuse the formatting of the `yaml`.

```
name: Metricbeat high FS percentage
type: metric_aggregation

es_host: localhost
es_port: 9200

index: metricbeat-*

buffer_time:
minutes: 1

metric_agg_key: system.filesystem.used.pct
metric_agg_type: max
query_key: beat.name.keyword
doc_type: metricsets

bucket_interval:
  minutes: 1

realert:
  minutes: 2

sync_bucket_interval: true
#allow_buffer_time_overlap: true
#use_run_every_query_size: true

max_threshold: 0.8

filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "system.filesystem.device_name: dev"
      analyze_wildcard: true
- term:
    metricset.name: filesystem

# (Required)
# The alert is use when a match is found

alert:
  - debug 
  - command
command: ["/home/ubuntu/sendToSlack.py","beat-name","%(beat.name.keyword)s","used_pc","%(system.filesystem.used.pct_max)s","mount_point","%(system.filesystem.mount_point)s"]
 # command: ["/home/ubuntu/sendToSlack.py","--beat-name","{match[beat.name.keyword]}","--mount_point","{match[system.filesystem.mount_point]}"]
 # command: ["/home/ubuntu/sendToSlack.py","--beat-name","{match[beat][name]}","--mount_point","{match[system][filesystem][mount_point]}"]
 #pipe_match_json: true
 #- command:
 #    command: ["/home/ubuntu/sendToSlack.py","%(system.filesystem.used.bytes)s"]
```

**Some observations**: 
   On testing the rule file using the command `python -m elastalert.test_rule rules/high_fs.yaml` I get the output

```
Successfully loaded Metricbeat high FS percentage

Got 149161 hits from the last 1 day

Available terms in first hit:

tags
beat.hostname
beat.name
beat.version
type
@timestamp
system.filesystem.available
system.filesystem.files
system.filesystem.mount_point
system.filesystem.free_files
system.filesystem.free
system.filesystem.device_name
system.filesystem.used.bytes
system.filesystem.used.pct
system.filesystem.total
host
@version
metricset.rtt
metricset.name
metricset.module
```

I should be able to access any of the fields mentioned above. When I run this rule using  `python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule rules/high_fs.yaml` a list is printed on the screen

```
@timestamp: 2017-10-18T17:15:00Z
beat.name.keyword: my_server_name
num_hits: 98
num_matches: 5
system.filesystem.used.pct_max: 0.823400020599
```

I am able to access all the key value pairs in this list. Anything thats outside the list fails with the `formatting` error.  Been stuck over this for long. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** A [reply](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1394) for the same problem on elastalert's github repo says that certain query types do not contain the full field data.

While I am not sure if this is the correct way to achieve what I was looking for but I was able to get the the desired output using the rule type `any` and writing my own filters. Here is how one of my rules file looks currently.

```
name: High CPU percentage
type: any

es_host: localhost
es_port: 9200

index: consumer-*
query_key:
  - beat.name

filter:
- range:
    system.cpu.total_norm_pct:
      from: 0.95
      to: 10.0

realert:
  minutes: 60

alert:
- command:
    command: ["/home/ubuntu/slackScripts/sendCPUDetails.py","{match[beat][name]}","{match[system][cpu][total_norm_pct]}"]
new_style_string_format: true
```

Hope it helps someone.